# Сборщик мусора удаляет делегат в неуправляемый код

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

Моё приложение - форма для проведения экзаменации. На просторах интернета нашел код, запрещающий закрывать/сворачивать форму любыми сочетаниями клавиш. На форме есть ToolStripTextBox, предназначенный для ввода пароля, а также ToolStipButton, при нажатии на который при правильно введенном пароле производится выход из формы. Но если неоднократно ввести и удалить данные в ToolStripTextBox, форма зависает и появляется следующая ошибка:

> "CallbackOnCollectedDelegate" : "Был произведен обратный вызов делегата типа "ExamTool v0.2!ExamTool_v0._2.LowLevelKeyboardHook+LowLevelK eyboardProcDelegate::Invoke", полученного сборщиком мусора. Это может привести к сбоям приложения, а также к повреждению или утрате данных. При передаче делегатов в неуправляемый код управляемое приложение должно поддерживать их существование, пока не будет гарантировано, что они больше никогда не будут вызваны."

Код класса, отвечающий за низкоуровневый перехват клавиатуры:

```
public class LowLevelKeyboardHook
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
    }

    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_1;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_2;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_3;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_4;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_5;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_6;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_7;
    private LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate m_callback_8;

    private IntPtr m_hHook;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_1;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_2;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_3;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_4;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_5;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_6;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_7;
    private IntPtr m_hHook_8;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(IntPtr lpModuleName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_win(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.RWin:
                case Keys.LWin:
                    return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_1, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_del(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {

            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Delete)
            {
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_3, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_ctrl(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.RControlKey:
                case Keys.LControlKey:
                    return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_2, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Alt)
            {
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_4, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt_tab(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.Alt:
                case Keys.Tab:
                    return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt_space(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.Alt:
                case Keys.Space:
                    return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_5, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_control_shift_escape(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.LControlKey:
                case Keys.RControlKey:
                case Keys.LShiftKey:
                case Keys.RShiftKey:
                case Keys.Escape:
                    return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_6, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_control_alt_del(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.LControlKey:
                case Keys.Alt:
                case Keys.Delete:
                    return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_7, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt_f4(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.Alt:
                case Keys.F4:
                    return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hHook_8, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public void SetHook()
    {
        m_callback = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_win;
        m_callback_1 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt_tab;
        m_callback_2 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_ctrl;
        m_callback_3 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_del;
        m_callback_4 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt;
        m_callback_5 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt_space;
        m_callback_6 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_control_shift_escape;
        m_callback_7 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_control_alt_del;
        m_callback_8 = LowLevelKeyboardHookProc_alt_f4;

        m_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_1 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_1, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_2 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_2, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_3 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_3, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_4 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_4, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_5 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_5, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_6 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_6, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_7 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_7, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
        m_hHook_8 = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_callback_8, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
    }

    public void Unhook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_1);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_2);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_3);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_4);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_5);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_6);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_7);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(m_hHook_8);
    }
}
```

К сожалению, абсолютно не представляю, как решить возникшую проблему...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612888/184217 - нэ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама проблема скорей всего не в классе, а за его пределами. Неизвестно как это вызывается, как хранится ссылка на класс и как она удаляется. Вообще, здесь толковый `IDisposable` бы реализовать.

Ну и нахукали вы здесь страшно. Зачем устраивать перехук одной и той же клавиши, с тем же успехом можно взять все уникальные клавиши и хукнуть все разом.

Потом, нужно заботиться о внешнем API класса, чтобы он был удобен для использования и не допускал ошибок при неаккуратном использовании, а так же был прост в использовании.

Итого получается:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

```
public class LowLevelKeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate int WindowsHookDelegate(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
    }

    private WindowsHookDelegate _callback;
    private IntPtr _hook;
    private bool _disposed;
    private bool _enabled;

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get => _enabled;
        set
        {
            if (_enabled == value)
                return;
            if (value)
                Hook();
            else
                Unhook();
            _enabled = value;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, WindowsHookDelegate lpfn, int hMod, int dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetModuleHandle(IntPtr lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    private int WindowsHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT>(lParam);
            switch (objKeyInfo.key)
            {
                case Keys.LShiftKey:
                case Keys.RShiftKey:
                case Keys.Escape:
                case Keys.Space:
                case Keys.Tab:
                case Keys.Alt:
                case Keys.RControlKey:
                case Keys.LControlKey:
                case Keys.RWin:
                case Keys.LWin:
                case Keys.Delete:
                case Keys.F4:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public LowLevelKeyboardHook()
    {
        _callback = WindowsHookProc;
    }

    private void Hook()
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _callback, GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero), 0);
    }

    private void Unhook()
    {
        CheckDisposed();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
        _hook = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(LowLevelKeyboardHook).FullName);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) 
        {
            CheckDisposed();
            _callback = null;
        }
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        Unhook();
        _disposed = true;
    }

    ~LowLevelKeyboardHook()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Немного подправил делегат и сигнатуры.

---

**Использовать просто**

Создать, положить в поле класса, который живет все время приложения, например главной формы.

```
private LowLevelKeyboardHook _hook = new();
```

Включить

```
_hook.Enabled = true;
```

Выключить

```
_hook.Enabled = false;
```

По окончании работы можно хук уничтожить, при этом если он активен, то он расхукается сам

```
_hook.Dispose();
```

Но даже если вы забудете вызвать `Dispose`, его вызовет сборщик мусора через финализатор `~LowLevelKeyboardHook()`. И сама по себе проблема вызова функции из неуправляемого кода после сборки будет устранена.

---

Еще я бы не хукал обычные, не управляющие клавиши, это может вызвать нездоровое поведение приложения. Например, если вы хукаете пробел, то ничего написать в форме с пробелом не получится, верно? Если хукаете <kbd>Tab</kbd>, то не получится перемещаться между инпутами используя эту клавишу. Любые такие ограничения должны быть минимальными, но достаточными, чтобы получить нужный эффект. Ничего лишнего блокировать не следует.

То есть можно оставить только это, и всё будет работать как надо.

```
case Keys.LShiftKey:
case Keys.RShiftKey:
case Keys.Alt:
case Keys.RControlKey:
case Keys.LControlKey:
case Keys.RWin:
case Keys.LWin:
```

---

Ну и дополнительно ко всему всякие локальные типа <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> можно обрабатывать не хуками, а менять поведение формы.